# Pypresence isn't changing my Discord Rich Presence

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

So, there's something called discord rich presence that shows stuff like what game someone is playing if the game supports it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyXCH.png). But, nothing shows up for me in Discord when using a python library called [pypresence](https://pypi.org/project/pypresence/). The code is straight from the pypresence docs (https://qwertyquerty.github.io/pypresence/html/info/quickstart.html).

**CODE:**

```
from pypresence import Presence
import time

client_id = 'my_client_id' # I put my client id in here, but I removed it for pretty obvious reasons
rpc = Presence(client_id)
rpc.connect()

rpc.update(state='Rich Presence using pypresence!')

while True:
    time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it had nothing to do with pypresence. I had forgot to turn on `Display Current Activity as a Status Message` in Settings>Activity Status.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Try updating the module `pip install -U pypresence` [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsF63.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a test build of Discord? You may have to manually adjust the pipe used. See the `pipe` kwarg of pypresence.Client or pypresence.Presence.

Iirc, the default target pipe is 0, standard Discord. There may be some auto detection, but these is the only reason I can think of for it not working.

Additionally ensure that in your Discord settings, you have a "Show the current game I'm playing" toggle which has to be enabled.